# How to query multiple claims in Oracle for one customer on a given day based on a few criteria

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to write a query in oracle that will return instances where a customer had

```
2+ claims on the same day
The 2+ claims share the same Drug ID
That 2+ claims share the same Customer ID 
The 2+ claims share the same store ID
```

I'm new to Oracle, so not too much. I'm learning hands on. I've tried to use google to write statements involving the count function but I'm not getting anywhere. Not sure if its the nuances or using count or oracle but I could use a pro's help and maybe if you're bored some logic explanation.

I'm expecting to see fields with individual claim detail listed out. I'd need the results to actual display the detail for each claim, not just summarize what customers have transactions that fit the criteria

Answer (score 0):

If the conditions concern the same group of rows:

```
group by trunc(claim_dat), drug_id, customer_id, store_id
having (count(*) >= 2)
```

If not, you may count by partition for each condition in a subquery and select the results with the conditions you want.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm expecting to see fields with individual claim detail listed out. I'd need the results to actual display the detail for each claim, not just summarize what customers have transactions that fit the criteria

If you want all the details of the claims then you probably want to use `COUNT` as an analytic function (rather than an aggregation function) and can use:

```sql
SELECT claim_date,
       drug_id,
       customer_id,
       store_id,
       insurance_id,
       other_columns
       -- ...
FROM   (
  SELECT claim_date,
         drug_id,
         customer_id,
         store_id,
         insurance_id,
         other_columns,
         -- ...,
         COUNT(*) OVER (
           PARTITION BY TRUNC(claim_date), drug_id, customer_id, store_id
         ) AS num_claims
  FROM   table_name
)
WHERE  num_claims   >= 2
AND    insurance_id =  'abcde_f'
```

or:

```sql
SELECT claim_date,
       drug_id,
       customer_id,
       store_id,
       insurance_id,
       other_columns
       -- ...
FROM   (
  SELECT claim_date,
         drug_id,
         customer_id,
         store_id,
         insurance_id,
         other_columns,
         -- ...,
         COUNT(*) OVER (
           PARTITION BY TRUNC(claim_date), drug_id, customer_id, store_id
         ) AS num_claims
  FROM   table_name
  WHERE  insurance_id =  'abcde_f'
)
WHERE  num_claims   >= 2
```

Comment: This is very helpful! I'm working in a very large database so I'm trying to add an additional identifier at the end to pare down the results, but its creating an invalid identifier error. What modification would I need to do to this add  the identifier below and not get an ora-00904
    and insurance_ID = 'abcde_f'

Comment: @Jake Added a couple of options depending on whether you want to filter before looking claims or after.

Comment: Ok this is moving in the right direction, I had to change it b/c it turns out drug_ID is in a different table. I'm trying to left join drug table based on an existing format in docs but struggling, I'm still working at it but I did export this without the DG ID identifier and the example I'm researching was in the data set. So this is going to work out.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this could help. Needed to work with some sample data, but you need to adjust it to your context:

```sql
WITH      --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
    tbl AS
        ( Select  1 "ID", 11 "STORE_ID", 101 "CUSTOMER_ID", 1001 "DRUG_ID", 'Claim no 1' "CLAIM", DATE '2024-02-01' "A_DATE" From Dual Union All
          Select  2, 11, 101, 1001, 'Claim no 2', DATE '2024-02-01' From Dual Union All
          Select  3, 11, 101, 1001, 'Claim no 3', DATE '2024-02-02' From Dual Union All
          Select  4, 12, 101, 1003, 'Claim no 4', DATE '2024-02-02' From Dual Union All
          Select  5, 13, 101, 1009, 'Claim no 5', DATE '2024-02-03' From Dual Union All
          Select  6, 11, 101, 1003, 'Claim no 6', DATE '2024-02-04' From Dual Union All
          --
          Select  7, 11, 102, 1007, 'Claim no 7', DATE '2024-02-05' From Dual Union All
          Select  8, 12, 102, 1003, 'Claim no 8', DATE '2024-02-06' From Dual Union All
          --
          Select  9, 11, 103, 1001, 'Claim no 9', DATE '2024-02-07' From Dual  
        ),
```

... create a CTE with all counters needed using Count() Over() analytic functions...

```sql
  counters AS
    ( Select    ID, CUSTOMER_ID, 
                Count(ID) Over(Partition By CUSTOMER_ID, A_DATE) "SAME_DAY",
                Count(ID) Over(Partition By CUSTOMER_ID, DRUG_ID) "SAME_DRUG",
                Count(ID) Over(Partition By CUSTOMER_ID, STORE_ID) "SAME_STORE",
                Count(Distinct CLAIM) Over(Partition By CUSTOMER_ID) "CUST_CLAIMS",
                STORE_ID, DRUG_ID, CLAIM, A_DATE
      From      tbl
      Order By  CUSTOMER_ID
    )
```

... now you could fetch any of the instances, some or all of them (with union)

```sql
--    M a i n   S Q L :
Select  CUSTOMER_ID, 'SAME_DAY' "INSTANCE_TYPE", To_Char(A_DATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd') "INSTANCE_VALUE", SAME_DAY "NUM_OF_INSTANCES", 
        CLAIM, 'Store ' || To_Char(STORE_ID) "DESCRIPTION_1", 'Drug ' || To_Char(DRUG_ID) "DESCRIPTION_2"
From    counters
Where   SAME_DAY >= 2
UNION ALL
Select  CUSTOMER_ID, 'SAME_DRUG' "INSTANCE_TYPE", To_Char(DRUG_ID) "INSTANCE_VALUE", SAME_DRUG "NUM_OF_INSTANCES", 
        CLAIM, 'Date ' || To_Char(A_DATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd') "DESCRIPTION_1", 'Store ' || To_Char(STORE_ID) "DESCRIPTION_2"
From    counters
Where   SAME_DRUG >= 2
UNION ALL
Select  CUSTOMER_ID, 'SAME_STORE' "INSTANCE_TYPE", To_Char(STORE_ID) "INSTANCE_VALUE", SAME_STORE "NUM_OF_INSTANCES", 
        CLAIM, 'Date ' || To_Char(A_DATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd') "DESCRIPTION_1", 'Drug ' || To_Char(DRUG_ID) "DESCRIPTION_2"
From    counters
Where   SAME_STORE >= 2
UNION ALL
Select  CUSTOMER_ID, 'CUSTOMER_CLAIMS' "INSTANCE_TYPE", To_Char(CUSTOMER_ID) "INSTANCE_VALUE", CUST_CLAIMS "NUM_OF_INSTANCES", 
        CLAIM, 'Date ' || To_Char(A_DATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd') "DESCRIPTION_1", 'Store ' || To_Char(STORE_ID) || ' | Drug ' || To_Char(DRUG_ID) "DESCRIPTION_2"
From    counters
Where   CUST_CLAIMS >= 2
```

```sql
/*      R e s u l t :
CUSTOMER_ID INSTANCE_TYPE   INSTANCE_VALUE    NUM_OF_INSTANCES CLAIM      DESCRIPTION_1                                   DESCRIPTION_2            
----------- --------------- ----------------- ---------------- ---------- ----------------------------------------------- -------------------------
        101 SAME_DAY        2024-02-01                       2 Claim no 1 Store 11                                        Drug 1001                
        101 SAME_DAY        2024-02-01                       2 Claim no 2 Store 11                                        Drug 1001                
        101 SAME_DAY        2024-02-02                       2 Claim no 3 Store 11                                        Drug 1001                
        101 SAME_DAY        2024-02-02                       2 Claim no 4 Store 12                                        Drug 1003                
        101 SAME_DRUG       1001                             3 Claim no 1 Date 2024-02-01                                 Store 11                 
        101 SAME_DRUG       1001                             3 Claim no 2 Date 2024-02-01                                 Store 11                 
        101 SAME_DRUG       1001                             3 Claim no 3 Date 2024-02-02                                 Store 11                 
        101 SAME_DRUG       1003                             2 Claim no 4 Date 2024-02-02                                 Store 12                 
        101 SAME_DRUG       1003                             2 Claim no 6 Date 2024-02-04                                 Store 11                 
        101 SAME_STORE      11                               4 Claim no 1 Date 2024-02-01                                 Drug 1001                
        101 SAME_STORE      11                               4 Claim no 2 Date 2024-02-01                                 Drug 1001                
        101 SAME_STORE      11                               4 Claim no 3 Date 2024-02-02                                 Drug 1001                
        101 SAME_STORE      11                               4 Claim no 6 Date 2024-02-04                                 Drug 1003                
        101 CUSTOMER_CLAIMS 101                              6 Claim no 1 Date 2024-02-01                                 Store 11 | Drug 1001     
        101 CUSTOMER_CLAIMS 101                              6 Claim no 2 Date 2024-02-01                                 Store 11 | Drug 1001     
        101 CUSTOMER_CLAIMS 101                              6 Claim no 3 Date 2024-02-02                                 Store 11 | Drug 1001     
        101 CUSTOMER_CLAIMS 101                              6 Claim no 4 Date 2024-02-02                                 Store 12 | Drug 1003     
        101 CUSTOMER_CLAIMS 101                              6 Claim no 5 Date 2024-02-03                                 Store 13 | Drug 1009     
        101 CUSTOMER_CLAIMS 101                              6 Claim no 6 Date 2024-02-04                                 Store 11 | Drug 1003     
        102 CUSTOMER_CLAIMS 102                              2 Claim no 7 Date 2024-02-05                                 Store 11 | Drug 1007     
        102 CUSTOMER_CLAIMS 102                              2 Claim no 8 Date 2024-02-06                                 Store 12 | Drug 1003    */
```

Note:
This could be pivoted or conditionaly aggregated, filtered, further processed and with different descriptions or with fixed columns - anything that suits your needs...
OR for all instances >= 2

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM counters
WHERE SAME_DAY >= 2 And SAME_DRUG >= 2 And SAME_STORE >= 2 And CUST_CLAIMS >= 2
```

```sql
/*
        ID CUSTOMER_ID   SAME_DAY  SAME_DRUG SAME_STORE CUST_CLAIMS   STORE_ID    DRUG_ID CLAIM      A_DATE  
---------- ----------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------- ---------- ---------- ---------- --------
         1         101          2          3          4           6         11       1001 Claim no 1 01.02.24
         2         101          2          3          4           6         11       1001 Claim no 2 01.02.24
         3         101          2          3          4           6         11       1001 Claim no 3 02.02.24    */
```

OR without filtering...

```sql
SELECT Distinct * 
FROM counters
ORDER BY ID
```

```sql
/*
        ID CUSTOMER_ID   SAME_DAY  SAME_DRUG SAME_STORE CUST_CLAIMS   STORE_ID    DRUG_ID CLAIM      A_DATE  
---------- ----------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------- ---------- ---------- ---------- --------
         1         101          2          3          4           6         11       1001 Claim no 1 01.02.24
         2         101          2          3          4           6         11       1001 Claim no 2 01.02.24
         3         101          2          3          4           6         11       1001 Claim no 3 02.02.24
         4         101          2          2          1           6         12       1003 Claim no 4 02.02.24
         5         101          1          1          1           6         13       1009 Claim no 5 03.02.24
         6         101          1          2          4           6         11       1003 Claim no 6 04.02.24
         7         102          1          1          1           2         11       1007 Claim no 7 05.02.24
         8         102          1          1          1           2         12       1003 Claim no 8 06.02.24
         9         103          1          1          1           1         11       1001 Claim no 9 07.02.24    */
```